# What is the equivalent of map<int, vector<int> > in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary

In C++ often do something like this:

```
typedef map<int, vector<int> > MyIndexType;
```

Where I then use it like this:

```
MyIndexType myIndex;
for( ... some loop ...)
{
  myIndex[someId].push_back(someVal);
}
```

If there was no entry in the map the code will insert a new empty vector and then append to it.

In Python it would look like this:

```
myIndex = {}

for (someId,someVal) in collection:
   try:
      myIndex[someId].append(someVal)
   except KeyError:
      myIndex[someId] = [someVal]
```

The try except is a bit ugly here. Is there a way to tell the dictionary an object type to insert when a KeyError is encountered at dictionary declaration time?

Comment: You should look in to multimap<> for your C++ code.

Comment: A multimap isn't necessarily the right data structure here. Nesting a vector inside a map is fine.

Comment: Agree: a multimap<int,int> would not retain the order of insertion as map<int,vector<int> > would.

Comment: This question is more about how to get the default entry into you collection. I also do us a lot of map<SomeKey, SomeStruct> collections with similar issues.

Comment: Don't use try except here, use the "in" operator (which calls has_key() for a dict)

Comment: @André: It depends on how often a missing key is encountered. `key in dict` could be more preferable if there are many missing keys. In any case dict.setdefault() or collections.defaultdict solve the problem.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You want to use:

```
from collections import defaultdict
myIndex = defaultdict(list)
myIndex[someId].append(someVal)
```

Standard Library [`defaultdict` objects](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#id3).

Example usage from the Python documentation:

```
>>> s = [('yellow', 1), ('blue', 2), ('yellow', 3), ('blue', 4), ('red', 1)]
>>> d = defaultdict(list)
>>> for k, v in s:
        d[k].append(v)

>>> d.items()
[('blue', [2, 4]), ('red', [1]), ('yellow', [1, 3])]
```

Answer (score 10):

Something like this perhaps:

```
myIndex = {}
for (someId,someVal) in collection:
    myIndex.setdefault(someId, []).append(someVal)
```

Comment: This is fundamentally a better way of doing things than than ddaa's response.

Comment: @Jerub: I disagree. Using a defaultdict is much easier to read, and has the advantage that it doesn't create and immediately destroy a new empty list even when not adding a new key (though in practice its slightly slower for lists - can be important for some types though).

Comment: I agree. setdefault() is the way to go.

Comment: `setdefault` is better when you're building a dictionary you're planning to pass to someone else (or you're simply have separate lookups to the same dictionary that shouldn't return a default value). `defaultdict` is better when you're using a dictionary in one place and/or all lookups to it should return the default value. (And rarely, a combination of `setdefault` and `get` can serve as a (temporary?) memory optimization of a code that uses `defaultdict` incorrectly)

Answer (score 2):

Just to complete the answer by Alastair:
There is also the **get** equivalent of **setdefault**, which is called **get** (and not getdefault, as one might think):

```
myIndex = {}
someId = None
myList = myIndex.get(someId, []) # myList is [] now
```

Answer (score 1):

From Python 2.5 and on you can get the behavior of setdefault or using defaultdict by implementing

```
__missing__(k)
```

as in note 10 [here](http://www.python.org/doc/2.5.2/lib/typesmapping.html).

Answer (score 0):

How about this?  It may not be performance-optimal, but I think it's the "simplest thing that could possibly work".

```
myIndex = {}

for (someId,someVal) in collection:
   if someId not in myIndex:
       myIndex[someId] = []
   myIndex[someId].append(someVal)
```

Comment: You are actually doing 2 lookups here. One more than needed.

Comment: This is called "look before you leap" (LBYL).  More pythonic is EAFP (google it :-) ).  In this case:
 try:
  myIndex[someID].append(someVal)
 except KeyError:
  myIndex[someID] = [someVal]

Of course, these days we have defaultdict which is even better :-)

Comment: the last line of the example should read myIndex[someId].append(someVal)

Note the lowercase 'a' in 'append'

Comment: I don't understand why this is downvoted: It's worse for this problem than `setdefault` or `defaultdict`, but it's more concise and clear than the try-except variant (at the expense of an additional lookup), and it's a valid solution. And in particular, it's a valid alternative to `setdefault` when the creation of the default is an expensive operation and it is as powerful as `__missing__` (i.e. more powerful than `defaultdict`).